# Scientific term for "flip and burn"

Tags: science-fiction, the-expanse

In *The Expanse*, (and other sci-fi keeping closer to the science than the fiction) the maneuver used to slow a space ship down is colloquialy referred to as [flip and burn](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=2ahUKEwjo1LGAwtHeAhWuT98KHTVeAx0QwqsBMAB6BAgJEAU&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov). What is the term used by real world aerospace engineers and pilots? Something like "retrograde thrust".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about a film or T&V show but rather scientific language.

Comment: [Space Exploration Stack Exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/) would be a more appropriate place to get some good answers to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Something like "retrograde thrust".

You pretty much nailed it there.

It's usually applied to *orbital manoeuvres* since we currently don't venture out much further than Earth/Lunar orbit

> A retrograde orientation is one that has the ship facing in the opposite direction from its direction of travel in its orbit.
>
> A retrograde burn is one in that direction, i.e. that subtracts from the ship's orbital speed.
>
> The effect of a retrograde burn is to lower the orbit's altitude (opposite the ship's current location); it is thus used when approaching a planet or moon and assuming a closed orbit, or when landing.
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://www.orbiterwiki.org/wiki/retrograde)</sup>

Essentially, *thrust in the opposite direction to current one* to slow down.

Comment: "Retrograde" just means facing or moving backwards, so you don't need to do the "flip" part at all to do a "retrograde burn," if you've got thrusters on the front of your ship.  The maneauover they do in the show is a sudden and drastic course correction in response to an emergency signal, whereas a "retrograde burn" could be used IRL simply to slow down while docking with a space station.  The "Flip & burn" move could reasonably be considered a *subset* of retrograde burn maneauovers, but it's not the only thing that falls under that description.